# Kubernetes version installed by minikube

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, minikube

How to know the kubernetes version that is installed by minikube?
I am aware of the kubectl version and the minikube version.

Comment: It should be like this `minikube config get kubernetes-version`. But not working for me.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Once your minikube is running, you can use `kubectl version` command to see the version of kubernetes server.

Also, when you start minikube using `minikube start`, kubernetes version is shown in stdout.

```
$ minikube start
Starting local Kubernetes v1.6.0 cluster...
```

You can supply the kubernetes version you want minikube to start by mentioning the `--kubernetes-version (The kubernetes version that the minikube VM will use (ex: v1.2.3))` flag.

```
$ minikube start --kubernetes-version v1.7.0
```

Comment: No way to know the version without firing the machine? 

Answer (score 0):

To find the Minikube version you can use the below command :

```
minikube version
```

In my macOS this was the version installed.

```
sidharth@Sidharths-MacBook-Air 1.18.4 % minikube version
minikube version: v1.25.1
commit: 3e64b11ed75e56e4898ea85f96b2e4af0301f43d
```

I also confirmed to check if `minikube start` command returned the same version and its pointing to the v.1.25.1

[image: minikube version returned by the command]

Reference : [Find Minikube version](https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/commands/version/)